# Append new element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a site, in which one will be able to ask a series of questions. I want the users to have the possibility to add however many questions they want, and whatever amount of options to each question. When the page loads up, it will show one question with one option-text box, together with four buttons, one for adding a new option, and one for adding a new question, and buttons for deleting questions (with options) or single options.

Using plain javascript, I've come up with a solution where one would have to click the buttons the amount of times which corresponds with the amount of questions/options one wants, before the text is added. The values in the text boxes would simply be erased for every time one clicked the button.

```
function addQuestion() {
numberOfQuestions++;
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML += (...);
}
```

How could I improve this with say, jQuery? I have tested this:

```
$("button#newQuestion")
    .click(
            function() {
                numberOfQuestions++;
                var container = document
                        .getElementById("container");
                container.append(...);
            });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show enough of your code that we can reproduce (a simplistic/minimal version of) what's going on? See: '[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)' for guidance. Incidentally, is there a problem with your current approach that you're trying to address? If so, what is that problem? Where are you stuck with the re-implementation/rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery this could be:

```js
numberOfQuestions=0;
$("button#newQuestion").click(function() {
  numberOfQuestions++;
  $("#container").append('<li>'+numberOfQuestions+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="newQuestion">Add Question</button>
<ul id="container">
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

`<div id="container"></div>
<button id="newQuestion">newQ</button>`

jQuery Code

    `$(document).ready(function(){
       var NOQ = $("#container").find(".q").length;
       $("#newQuestion").click(function() {
           NOQ++;
           $("#container").append("<div id='q"+NOQ+"' class='q'>Question "+NOQ+"?</div>");
        }); 
    });`

jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rL6xmdfh/3/